# Python Assertion Exception with Multiprocssing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have Python code that uses multiprocessing multiple times over the steps of a process.  It seems to be working, but I often see the following message:

```
Exception AssertionError: AssertionError('can only test a child process',) in <Finalize object, dead> ignored
```

I'm not exactly sure what this means or what I'm doing that causes it.
The script otherwise completes successfully and seems to have correctly finished.

I've been following this pattern for using multiprocessing.
Is there something missing, like some sort of cleanup, that I should be doing?

If these messages can be ignored, can I suppress them somehow?

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MultiProcess:
    queue = None

    def __init__(self, nb_workers):
        self.queue = mp.JoinableQueue()
        self.processes = [mp.Process(target=self.doprocessing, args=[]) for i in range(nb_workers)]
        for p in self.processes:
            p.start()

    def addToQueue(self, item):
        self.queue.put(item)

    def doprocessing(self):
        while True:
            item = self.queue.get()
            if item is None:
                break
            # Do some work with item
            self.queue.task_done()

    def terminate(self):
        self.queue.join()
        for p in self.processes:
            p.terminate()

r = MultiProcess(config.NUM_PROCESSORS)
for f in mylist.keys():
    r.addToQueue({"id": f})
r.terminate()
```

Comment: Interestingly, `assert("hello",)` → `<stdin>:1: SyntaxWarning: assertion is always true, perhaps remove parentheses?`. Might be related.

Comment: What does `mylist` look like?